# WordPress api returns distinct data

Tags: rest-api

I am developing a restful api for wordpress blog. In a url I'm returning the details of categories of that blog. The same api returns array in one blog and object in another.

The code is-

```
function categories(){
    $categories = get_categories(array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ));
    return $categories;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ( $server ) {
    $server->register_route( 'categories', '/categories', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'categories',
    ));
});
```

Here is the output-

Blog 1

[image]

Blog 2

[image]

I need same type of data to be returned, so that I can further process that data.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the built-in API? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/

Comment: Yes, there is. I need some of URL's that built in api doesn't provide. And I don't want to partially depend on built-in api.